# Error populating HTML input with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, dom

I have a value i get from PHP code and i want to insert int into a input field.

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("advSetting1").value = '.$myvalue1.' </script>';
```

with this input field

```
 <input id="advSetting1" type="text" name="timeout">
```

This code is not giving me any error and the string i get from $myvalue1 is a string with a number like 66.

When i use the same code but with a string that is formatted like 8.8.4.4 i get this error *SyntaxError: unexpected token: numeric literal*

How can i resolve this issue? Any hints? Thanks for the time and , eventualy, the answer :)

Comment: Try: `"'.$myvalue1.'"`. That is (spaced out to make it easy to see) `" ' .$myvalue1.' "`. Now the real question is what are you going to do if there is a `"` or `'` in that string.

Comment: Ty Tigger it works ;)

Comment: It is an error **populating JavaScript with PHP**

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape JavaScript special characters when you print a string from PHP to JavaScript. The easiest way is to use the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> document.getElementById("advSetting1").value = '.json_encode($myvalue1).' </script>';
```

It prints a valid JavaScript value declaration for any type of data.